# Cannot track google maps adsense earnings?

Tags: maps, adsense

I have been using Adsense with Google Maps with my website from last few months now.

Am using the API as per-
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/advertising

However, when I wanted to check the gains I am making here, I could not see them in Adsense UI. I am using a 'BUTTON' ad unit and I fail to find any earnings under this ad unit size. I have decent amount of traffic with more than 1 million page views each month.

Can someone using Adsense with Google Maps help me find these earnings?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To track your map AdUnit performance, you need to create a new custom channel in your AdSense account. Go to "My ads" tab and click "Custom channels" and then "New custom channel". Give your new channel a name and save it. Your will get a channel ID, say it is "123456789". The second step is to go to your javascript code where you add your map AdUnit. Add a new option channelNumber: '123456789' in your adUnitOptions. That's it.